# Find the lowest n such that no members of a list have a member with that value

Tags: python

What's the most pythonic way of finding the first "untaken" integer, where an integer is taken if the value of a list's .slot member equals that integer?

My approach:

```
def find_min_untaken(l, max):
   for i in range(max+1):
      if len([c for c in l if c.slot == i]) == 0:
         return i
   else:
      return None
```

Comment: A sample input and output would help here…

Answer (score -1):

The function next returns the first integer that's not in the list. If no integer is found, it returns None.

```
def find_min_untaken(l, max):
    return next((i for i in range(1, max) if i not in l), None)
```